# No entiendo este error de identación

Tags: python

```
class Comprador(models.Model):
    nombre_y_apellido = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    rut = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(max_length = 12)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    telefono = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(max_length = 11)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField
    productoFavorito = models.CharField(max_length = 25, choices = Producto)
    puntuacion_del_producto = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = 
    puntuacion, default = 'Select')
    Direccion = models.TextField(max_length = 200)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.datos_comprador
```

El error:

```
line 32
    def __str__(self):
                       ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

No entiendo muy buen porque sale este error aquí, según yo todo estaría correcto
Seria de gran ayuda si alguien me pudiera ayudar

Comment: Puede ser por múltiples temas, sobre todo por el editor. Aquí hay una pregunta en SOEN con varias respuestas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level

Comment: Cuando se mezclan tabuladores y espacios sale un error más concreto a este problema. Si se va a la pregunta original (no a las ediciones posteriores), se ve que `def __str__(self)` está identado sólo con 3 espacios, en lugar de 4.

Comment: Gracias, pude arreglarlo, lo que hice fue borrar toda la identacion y volverla a hacer así para tener todo correcto y ya no me lanza error